# Using class method as callback wtih addEventListener fails after 1 event fire

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create my own product card carousel.

Using JavaScript to enhance scrolling from the user.

I created the class for the slider, and inside the class I set up a bunch of addEventListeners on the slider.

Ever since I moved the code to a class, the mousedown, mouseup and mousemove event only seem to fire once.

After they fire, the next even causes a ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.mouseDown is not a function
```

On line

```
// Mouse drag
this.slides.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.mouseDown(e); }, false);
```

I've tried doing the whole

```
let self = this;
this.slides.addEventListener("mousedown", self.mouseDown, false);
```

Which did not work either.

When I console.log here:

```
this.slides.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { console.log(this); this.mouseDown(e); }, false);
```

The this reference looks correct.

[image]

How can I correctly bind these listeners to methods in the object they were declared in, correctly?

Relevant code below...

```
class Slider {  
    id = "";
    slides = null;

    posRefx = 0;
    posRefy = 0;
    mousedown = false;

    constructor(sliderID) {
        this.id = sliderID;
    }

    init() {
        this.slides = document.getElementById(this.id).getElementsByClassName('slides')[0];

        this.slides.style.cursor = 'grab';

        if (this.slides.addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            this.slides.addEventListener("mousewheel", (e) => { this.onMouseMove(e); }, false);

            // Firefox
            this.slides.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", (e) => { this.onMouseMove(e); }, false);

            // Touch devices
            this.slides.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => { this.touchStart(e); }, false);
            this.slides.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => { this.touchMove(e); }, false);

            // Mouse drag
            this.slides.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.mouseDown(e); }, false);
            this.slides.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => { this.mouseUp(e); }, false);
            this.slides.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => { this.mouseMove(e); }, false);
        } 


    mouseDown(event) {
        ...
    }

    mouseUp(event) {
        ...
    }

    mouseMove(event) {
        ...
    }
}

var mySlider = new Slider("my-slider-id");
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    mySlider.init();    
});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `this` to see what it is on subsequent calls? Hard to say what could be causing the problem from the code here, a live Stack Snippet that illustrates the issue would probably be a lot more debuggable

Comment: Ok I added a console log screenshot. The this context looks correct.

Comment: You have a `mouseDown` function and a `mousedown` boolean property, which are very similar and could cause problems. By any chance are you assigning to `mouseDown` inside of one of the functions, instead of to `mousedown`? (Can't see it given the code in the question - best to include all relevant code in the question)

Comment: Wow, well spotted. Yeah that was it, that would have taken me ages to figure that out.